# Docker run container slow

Tags: performance, docker, containers

I run the following command several times and get very closely results.

```
➜ time docker run --rm -it alpine:3.7 true
docker run --rm -it alpine:3.7 true  0.03s user 0.03s system 5% cpu 2.263 total
```

`docker run` takes 2 or 3 seconds to execute one simple command in a very small image. I think it's a performance issue, may be cpu/memory/io bottleneck.
I want to know how to figure out this problem?

Comment: I think 2-3 seonds for communicating with the docker API, allocating the necessary resources and spinning up a new container is pretty reasonable.

Comment: @Turing85, sorry, I forgot to add the env I used. I used two VMs with same cpu/memory on the same host. One is always less than 1 second, the other is always higher than 2 seconds. That command can be done in less than 0.5 second on my Mac.